# pgfkeys limit the possible values of a key

Tags: pgfkeys

I use `pgfkeys` to hold specific values (text). Now I'd be able to limit the possible values of that key (only some values valid). How is this possible with `pgfkeys`? (I saw `.is choice` but don't know how to use this to limit key values since its primarily use is for the `.code` or `.style` handler)

Comment: What't the current codes when no limit on key values is added?

Comment: Up to now, I use normal value keys, initialized with the `.initial` handler

Comment: So you want to use `\pgfkeys(getvalue|valueof)` with that key while have the ability to only accept selected values? I mean, alternatively, you can use sth like `\pgfkeys{mykey/.is choice, mykey/value1/.code={\def\store@value{value1}}}`.

Comment: Hm `\def` is globally right? If so it if course would be much nicer to do this only with pgfkeys, but if this isn't possible there's no way around it.

Comment: `\def` is local to the current group, `\gdef` is global.

Comment: Sounds good to me, `store@value` is then the name of the macro in which the value is stored right? (so to access the value I just use `\strore@value` instead of `\pgfkeysvalueof{key}`)

Comment: Yes. And you can choose other macro names.

Comment: Ok, nice would you make an Answer out of this as the solution of this issue? (and just being curious using the @ sign is just because of style and so that the macro cannot
 be used normally in normal LaTeX or are there any other reasons for this?)

Comment: "so that the macro cannot be used normally in normal LaTeX ... ?" Yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can define the key as

```tex
\pgfkeys{
  mykey/.is choice,
  mykey/value1/.code={\def\mykey@value{#1}},
  mykey/value2/.code={\def\mykey@value{#1}},
  % more allowed values
}
```

and use `\mykey@value` to retrieve the value passed to `mykey`, like `\pgfkeysvalueof{mykey}` if it is defined by `\pgfkeys{mykey/.initial}`.